# MySQL Join from multiple tables with GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I am trying to select data from 3 separate tables, where 2 of those contains multiple rows of data. The sql query i am using is this, but i am experiencing that when i run it, if either taskdependees or tasksdependencies have zero result, the whole task is not showing.

```
SELECT t.*, GROUP_CONCAT(a.DependenciesId) as DiesId, GROUP_CONCAT(b.DependeesId) as DeesId FROM tasks t JOIN tasksdependencies a ON a.TasksId=t.TasksId JOIN taskdependees b ON b.TasksId=t.TasksId GROUP BY t.TasksId
```

What am  I doing wrong in this query?

Comment: try a left join instead of a join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` , inner join will give row if there is association is present in both tables while left will return the rows from left table even if they are not associated

```
SELECT t.*, GROUP_CONCAT(a.DependenciesId) as DiesId,
 GROUP_CONCAT(b.DependeesId) as DeesId 
FROM tasks t
LEFT JOIN tasksdependencies a ON a.TasksId=t.TasksId
LEFT JOIN taskdependees b ON b.TasksId=t.TasksId 
GROUP BY t.TasksId
```

Comment: very usefull! i was posting a question like this and I found the answer, really thank you :-)